# Simulink block equivalent to diff() function in Matlab for Discrete Derivative in unit time

Tags: matlab, simulink, derivative

How do I implement the `diff()` function available in Matlab using `Simulink` block?

I need to read a sequence of digital sensor data `(x,y)` where, `x=[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, ... 100]`.  I want to calculate the change in x i.e. `del_x`. My assumption is that since it is a sequence of data, I can assume time as unit time `t=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ... 20]`.

Now I tried this simple model in Simulink with `Model Configuration Parameters` being:

```
Start time: 0.0
Stop time: 20
Solver Option = Fixed-step
Solver: discrete (no continuous states)
Fixed-step size (fundamental sample time): 1
```

[image: Simple Discrete Derivative test in Simulink]

Here, `simin` is equal to the input array x as described above. But `simout` becomes `del_x = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35 ... 100]`. So my question is, shouldn't the change in x (or `simout`) be `del_x = [0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, ... ]` since the change in x is always changing constantly by 5? In Matlab, `diff()` function gives me the desired result.

Using the equation:
`del_x = (x[i] - x[i-1])/(t[i]-t[i-1]) = (x[i] - x[i-1])/(1)`

Why is the output the delayed version `x[t-1]` of the input `x[t]` instead of change in x? Isn't the `Discrete Derivative block` supposed to operate identical to `diff()` function in Matlab? Also the `Difference block` gives the same undesired result. Just for bigger picture sake, I need to export a larger version of the Simulink model into C++ code in order to get the `error` and `change in error` of the sensor in order to implement a closed-loop control system but this simple simulation doesn't give the result I want.

**UPDATE:** It works with Matlab Function block with `diff()` inside. But Simulink needs to go through a long compilation stage just to implement it. Isn't there something simple that I am missing here?

[image: Matlab function block implementation of diff() function]

**UPDATE2:** All sample times are the same i.e. `1` (Display->Sample Time->All option).

[image]

Comment: You may want to use the causal operator `Z(f(x)-f(x-1)) = 1-z^-1`, or have I missed something?

Comment: If I use the Difference block `(z-1)/z` which is mathematically equivalent to your suggestion, `simout` is the same as I described. Its just [x(2) ... x(20)] given the input [x(1) x(2) ... x(20)] which is not what I wanted. But the `diff()` function in Matlab seems to work. Is there something with my Configuration Parameters for Fixed-step simulation?

Comment: Are you using a sample time of 1 in your From Workspace block? Have you checked all the signals are of sample time 1 (see http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/how-to-view-sample-time-information.html)?

Comment: Yes, all the sample times are 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set your source (From Workspace) to output one sample per time instant. Currently I think all of your data is going out at the same instant. Your simin in "From workspace" should be similar to the following struct for your case.

```
simin.time = 0:20;
simin.signals.values = (0:5:100)';
simin.signals.dimensions = 1;
```

Now if you set your sample time to 1 and run your model for 20 steps then you should get your desired output.

For this data your code in MATLAB Function will not do what you want. You need to implement the diff with a persistent variable to match other blocks with delay.

Comment: Ah, so this was what I was not doing right. Thank you so much, it works now.